making my floppy bird jump animations make my game poses in unity
So I'm working on my first game using unity, it's a simple floppy bird re-creation, I follower a video, but the video didn't include how to animate your characters, thus I wanted to learn how to animate it myself
I just started to add an animation when the bird flies (after hitting the spacebar), and as I mentioned it would only be triggered after hitting the spacebar so I used a Boolean in the transition, and used the following script to connect the animation to the actual thing
this is the script I used
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BirdScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // inaisly the script is not aware of the things we added into the object
    //we need to make those conctions using a refrance
    public Rigidbody2D BirdRigidBody;
    public float flapStentgh;
    public LogicScript logic;
    public bool AliveBird = true;
    public Animator BirdAnimator;
    //after making the varible go back to unity and drag the rigid body in 

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        logic = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("logic").GetComponent<LogicScript>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)==true &&AliveBird) {
            BirdRigidBody.velocity = Vector2.up * flapStentgh;
            BirdAnimator.SetBool("flapping", true);
        }
        if (transform.position.y <-17)
        {
            logic.GameOver();
            AliveBird=false;
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        logic.GameOver();
        AliveBird = false;
    }
}


the comments are my notes during the tutorial so don't pay so much attention to it
the problem that accrued is that now after I hit the spacebar the game pauses, it doesn't crash, just poses , I tried to look into some keyboard shortcuts, but found nothing
and the once I removed the  BirdAnimator.SetBool("flapping", true); from my script it went back to functioning normally(without the animations of course), so I assume the problem is there
I hope they're would be someone who can help me, or provide an explanation of why this is happening
Edit:
someone wanted me to add the animator controller, thus here it is



I'm assuming there is an error message and you have Error Pause selected. Please include the error message in your question. It is likely that you do not have a bool paramater called "flapping" in your animator.

Can you include screenshot of the bird's Animator Controller too?
